# Links displaying as full urls

Tags: windows, wordpress, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I recently through together a quick wordpress site for a friend. They're in a different state and I don't have access to my friend's device. When he goes to the website he sees what's in the image below; basically all the links are displaying full urls. I looked at it in IE, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, and none of them do it for me. Is this a setting in the browser or in Windows that would show the full URL? He's not tech savvy, so he wouldn't have anything like Firebug or Developer Tools installed. It happens for him in both IE and Chrome, so I'm wondering if it could be an accessibility setting on his device. I doubt it's the theme, but I'm willing to swap it out if it is.

[image: This is what my client sees]

Comment: If he is somehow viewing the print stylesheet for the site, it could display links that way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your friend is viewing the site in a way that displays the print stylesheet information.

In Chrome, I opened the developer tools, went to Emulation, and turned on the Print styles, and ended up with this:

[image: Site with Print Styles]